# Unsure How to Dynamically Paste a Formula To Last Column and Last Row

Tags: vba, excel

VBA question using Excel 2016 (64 bit)

I have header data in the first two columns (A:B) and the top row (1). I would like to dynamically paste a formula downward, starting from cell C2, to the last row *and* the last column. The working prototype is as follows:

```
    Dim LstCol As Long
        LstCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Range(Cells(2, "C"), Cells(2, LstCol)).Value =         "=INDEX(RC1,MATCH(R1C,RC2,0))"
    Dim LstRow As Long
        LstRow = Cells(1, Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range(Cells(2, "C"), Cells(2, LstRow)).Value = "=INDEX(RC1,MATCH(RC1,R2C,0))"
```

The first Dim works as intended. The formula is successfully deployed throughout the second row to the final column (or perhaps it starts at the last column and moves leftward). However, the second Dim stops on an error. I'm unsure how to spread the data from the last row (to the last column) upwards to the second row (and the corresponding last column).

In my example, the first two columns have header data from 1 to 5330 (A1:B5330). I also have header data in the first row (C1:AX1). My target is to fill the formula =INDEX($A2,MATCH(D$1,$B2,0)) from C2:AX5330 dynamically.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: From the first glance, you have an incorrect expression *(semantically speaking)* for `LstRow`. The line should be `LstRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` instead *(you have `Rows.Count` as value for `Column`)*

Comment: If you want to insert a formula, you need to use `Range.Formula` and not `Range.Value`

Comment: index and match formula is wrong.

Comment: INDEX(array, row_num, [column_num])

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly qualify your instances of `Range` and `Cells` with a worksheet. You can either directly do this, dim a worksheet variable, or use a `With` block like so:

```
Dim LRow as Long

With ThisworkBook.Sheets("????")
    LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
    .Range("C2:AX5330").Formula = "=INDEX($A2,MATCH(D$1,$B2,0))" 'Make sure your cell references are correct here
    .Range("C2:AX5330").Value = .Range("C2:AX55330").Value 'Place as values instead of formula
End With
```